# Assign and recall windows with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard

I would like to be able to **assign** numbers to windows with a keyboard shortcut like:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (different numbers for different windows or desktops)

and then **recall** them with a keyboard like:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

The specific modifier does not matter much. I used to do this with AutoHotkey in Windows. Can I do this in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a Mac-based macro program such as [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) by Stairways Software. Although its interface is very different, it's similarly powerful, if not more powerful than AutoHotkey. The program includes a tutorial and comprehensive documentation.

Comment: Thanks - before I buy this, how can I be sure that I can do what I asked above?